# The valid codeword digits 0, 1, . . . , 7, the number of 0s must be odd. Determine how many such code-words of the length n-digits exist.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Suppose, the code-words of a code can contain
only digits (0, 1, 2. 3. 4. 5,6, 7) while for a code-word, to be a valid code-word, the number of 0s must be odd.
1)how many such code-words of the length n-digits exist.
2)how to Set up the recurrence relation giving the number of code-words an of the length n and find the
3)how-to solution of this recurrence relation?

My solution:
codeword digits =( 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) and 0 odd number.So, a1=7.ending with non-zero= 7an−1.So, an=7an-1+8^n-1 -an-2.then an=6an-1+8^n-1 (actually i solve this like that but I have doubt about my selfe.maybe it's not perfectly correct.and I don't understand how to decorate this.) please some one help me I want to learn to solve like those type of problem solve solution

Comment: Please solve this problem, anyone. i will grateful to you

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: unfortunately, it was posted two times. I already deleted it once

Comment: I noticed. Parhaps my accusations were a bit harsh; if so, sorry. Still, it would be a good idea to edit your question and show us what you have tried. Someone will be more likely to help you if they see that you have put in effort and are trying to learn.

Comment: codeword digits =( 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) and 0 odd number.So, a1=7.ending with non-zero= 7an−1.So, an=7an-1+8^n-1 -an-2.then an=6an-1+8^n-1      (actually i solve this like that but I have doubt about my selfe.maybe it's not perfectly correct.and I don't understand how to decorate this.) please some one help me I want to learn to solve like those type of problem solve solution

Comment: I also got a_n = 6a_(n-1) + 8^(n-1). Do you know how to reduce this into a general formula from here?

Comment: i know the general formula is α1r1^n+α2r2^n.but i dont know how to reduce from here

Answer (score 1):

### Deriving a recurrence relation

To make a recurrence relation for $a_n$, let's break into cases based on whether the last digit is 0.

How many possibilities exist where the last digit is 0? Well, we just need any codeword of length $n-1$ with an **even** number of 0s, so that we'll get an odd number of 0s after we include the extra 0 on the end. The total number of codewords of length $n-1$ is $8^{n-1}$, and $a_{n-1}$ of those have an odd number of zeros, so $8^{n-1} - a_{n-1}$ is the number with an even number of zeros.

How many possibilities exist where the last digit is not 0? Well, the last digit could be anything from 1-7 (7 options) and the first $n-1$ digits could be any codeword of length $n-1$ with an odd number of 0s ($a_{n-1}$ options), so we have $7 a_{n-1}$ options in total.

Combining those two cases, we find $a_n = 8^{n-1} - a_{n-1} + 7 a_{n-1}$, or $a_n = 6 a_{n-1} + 8^{n-1}$. We can also quickly check the base case $a_1 = 1$.

### Solving the recurrence relation

There are some fancy tricks that let you solve lots of recurrence relations, but those are also more complicated to learn. I'd start out with a simpler strategy: Just plug into the recurrence relation repeatedly and try to find a pattern. In this case, we see:
$$
\begin{align}
a_n &= 8^{n-1} + 6 a_{n-1} \\
&= 8^{n-1} + 6(8^{n-2} + 6 a_{n-2}) \\
&= 8^{n-1} + 6 \cdot 8^{n-2} + 6^2 a_{n-2} \\
&= 8^{n-1} + 6 \cdot 8^{n-2} + 6^2 (8^{n-3} + 6 a_{n-3}) \\
&= 8^{n-1} + 6 \cdot 8^{n-2} + 6^2 \cdot 8^{n-3} + 6^3 a_{n-3} \\
&\quad \vdots \\
&= 8^{n-1} + 6 \cdot 8^{n-2} + 6^2 8^{n-3} + 6^3 8^{n-4} + \cdots + 6^{n-2} 8^1 + 6^{n-1} a_1 \\
&= 8^{n-1} \left( 1 + \frac{6}{8} + \left(\frac 6 8\right)^2 + \cdots \left( \frac 6 8 \right)^{n-1}\right) \\
&= 8^{n-1} \left( \frac{1 - \left(\frac 6 8 \right)^n} {1-\frac 6 8} \right) \\
&= 8^{n-1} \cdot 4\left(1 - \left(\frac 3 4 \right)^{n}\right) \\
&= 2^{3n-1} - 2^{n-1} 3^n
\end{align}
$$

So the final formula is $a_n = 2^{3n-1} - 2^{n-1} 3^n$.

### Pointer for further reading

If you want to read about general methods for solving such recurrence relations, instead of just rolling up your sleeves and simplifying everything by hand like I did above, then you should look up "Solving non-homogeneous linear recurrence relations". There are a couple of different methods (that mostly work for the same reasons behind the scenes). I don't have one particular link to recommend but you can find a lot of articles, course slides, YouTube tutorials, etc. if you get interested and want to Google it.